# How to save and retrieve data from ArrayList using shared preference?

Tags: android, arraylist, save, preference

Please help me with this. I have more than 70 images. How can I save them using shared preference?

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>
    list.add(R.drawable.image1);
    list.add(R.drawable.image2);
    list.add(R.drawable.image3);

    position = new Random().nextInt(list.size());
    basic_random_image.setImageResource((Integer)list.get(position));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values).

Comment: BTW, this does not seem like a good idea.  Persisting resource IDs seems dangerous.  These IDs are auto-generated with each build.  So the values that you save may be invalid the next time you build (or the next time a user upgrades).

Answer (score 0):

To save images in SharedPreferences is rather a bad idea.
If you use images from your res then you can get them when you need by `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourPic)`.
If you download from internet - just save them to SDCard or use some libs for caching images.